# Origin of the name "Cauchy sequence" in abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, cauchy-sequences

I know the origin in analysis as it is derived from our good old chap Cauchy himself. However I have read about Cauchy sequences in algebra, I'll use groups for this one, let $G$ be a group and $G_i\triangleleft G$ for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$ along with $G_0=G$ and our filtration is then

$$G_0\supseteq G_1 \supseteq G_1\supseteq\ldots$$
Next we let $\{x_i\}$ be a sequence, it is a cauchy sequence if and only if we have that for a given $m\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists an $N$ such that $\forall i,j > N$ we have that $x_i x_j^{-1}\in G_m$.

I think I got that right from memory, anyhow I am curious as to why this is called a cauchy sequence? While I understand there are definitional simularities in how it is phrased, the whole "Find $N$ such that $i,j>N$" bit is right from the traditional real analysis definition. I can even see the parallel between $\epsilon$ in the analysis definition and our $m$ here which really marks a normal subgroup. In this chain we have that the "size" of the groups get's smaller (for simplicity sake assuming it doesn't stagnate), so $m\to\infty$ would be a parallel to $\epsilon\to 0$. And of course $x_i x_j^{-1}\in G_m$ is parallel to $|x_i-x_j|<\epsilon$.

Is this the reason why it is called cauchy because of these striking similarities? Where did this name come from? Who came with it for algebra?

Comment: You need some proprerties on the $G_i$, and these are Cauchy in a particular metric - that is, there is a sense in which this is the same definition as in analysis. Define $d(x,y)=2^{-k}$ where $k$ is the largest value such that $xy^{-1}\in G_k$. (So you need $\bigcap G_i=\{1\}$, and $0$ if $x=y$. You need some additional condition on the $G_i$, I think, for this to be a metric, but in that metric, this is a Cauchy sequence in the analytic sense.

Comment: That is why I am not going for the analytical but algebraic sense of it, the definitions I see on these don't state any metric or anything, just groups and normal subgroups.

Comment: But the point is, your definition is the same, and you wanted to know what the origin was. The origin is that there is a metric on $G$ in which these are exactly the Cauchy sequences. It comes from the analytic term.

Comment: So it is really the parallel I noticed, do you happen to know who came with it first for algebra and possible in what work?

Comment: I suspect it first came with the study of the $p$-adic numbers - where $G=\mathbb Z$ and $G_k=p^k\mathbb Z$. But I don't know the exact history, no.

Comment: The Wikipedia page has a brief outline. It allows the intersection of the $G_i$ to be non-trivial. It doesn't say anything about the history, though. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence#In_groups